# ¿Cómo optimizar el llamado a Directions API (Google) en una aplicación de taxi?

Tags: javascript, flutter, app, map, routing

Buen día a todos,

Estamos desarrollando una aplicación de taxi de la cual tenemos la mayor parte desarrollada, sin embargo, quisiéramos optimizar los costos de Google Maps Platform.

Antes de comentar mi duda, resumo la lógica de la aplicación luego de haber revisado videotutoriales y cursos que te orientan para el desarrollo de apps de taxi:

- Luego de que la aplicación tiene el LatLng del punto de partida y de destino. Se hace un llamado a la webservice de [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/quickstart#getting_directions) para obtener los puntos de la ruta que formarán el polyline en la aplicación.
- Cuando el conductor se dirige a recoger al cliente o cuando inicia el viaje desde el punto de partida al destino, a medida que cambia la posición del conductor, la aplicación tiene que ir haciendo llamados a Directions API para obtener este nuevo polyline y dibujar en el mapa ([Ver imagen](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ec1be3c959b74e15fc5990c8879cc9b1a7326ddb/687474703a2f2f7265732e636c6f7564696e6172792e636f6d2f6879706572747261636b2f696d6167652f75706c6f61642f76313532353332393636392f637573746f6d65722e706e67)).
- Según los precios de Google Platform ([Ver aquí](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing#:%7E:text=Google%20Maps%20Platform%20offers%20a,exceeds%20%24200%20in%20a%20month)), con el caso supuesto de que un viaje promedio tenga 10km de distancia daría y la aplicación use 5 metros de precisión, tendría como resultado aproximadamente 2000 solicitudes y sin considerar que lo mismo lo tiene que ver el cliente. Esto no resulta rentable puesto que lo que cobraría Google sería más de lo que se le cobraría al cliente.

Entonces mi pregunta es:

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera para evitar tantas llamadas a Directions API?
¿Se podría reducir a solo una llamada por viaje?

PD:
Pensamos que se podría ir quitando los points de un polyline e ir refrescando el mapa, pero no sabemos como se podría identificar que el vehículo está pasando por ese polyline, ya que los GPS tienen un margen de error que no es muy exacto.

Comment: Has probado utilizar ArcGIS Runtime API?, es libre, hasta donde tengo entendido hay otras Api gratuitas obviamente la parte estética seria diferente a las de google pero podrías optar por un plan b.

Comment: Hola. si estas requiriendo opiniones te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.